# asp.net mvc 3 razor and html iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, razor

I have page there is button which shows iframe where is small list with clickable rows like this:

```
<tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Show", "Messages", new { id = item.FriendID }))'">
```

So my problem is when user click on tr Redirect is working but on i frame i want to redirect my parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of location.href, use top.href or parent.href

```
<tr onclick="top.href = '@(Url.Action("Show", "Messages", new { id = item.FriendID }))'">
```